# Replacing the elements of a list with elements of another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists as follow:

```
l={a,b,c,d}
```

and

```
ll={{1,x},{2,x},{3,x},{4,x}}
```

I want to replace the x's with a,b,c and d so that the outcome would be:

```
{{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}}
```

How would one does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should make the job:

```
ll[[;; , 2]] = l;
ll
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}

Or equivalently:

```
MapThread[#1 /. {x -> #2} &, {ll, l}]
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}

Note that the output is the same, but what the code is doing is different, and you might prefer one solution or the other depending on your specific case.

Answer (score 7):

```
Transpose[{ll[[All, 1]], l}]
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}

My preferred method would be the first method proposed in Fraccalo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {a, b, c, d};

lb = {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[la &, lb, {All, -1}]
```

{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}

Answer (score 2):

```
l = {a, b, c, d};
ll = {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}};
```

Using `Thread`:

```
Thread[{ll[[All, 1]], l}]

(*{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ReplacePart`:**

```
l = {a, b, c, d}
ll = {{1, x}, {2, x}, {3, x}, {4, x}}

ReplacePart[ll, Thread[Position[ll, x] -> l]]
```

> {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}}

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[{First@#2,#1}&,{l,ll}]

(* {{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d}} *)
```